# XAMPP MySQL failing to start on Windows7

Tags: mysql, xampp

MySql is failing to run on my XAMPP v3.2.2 software. This is running on Windows 7.

I have tried changing the port for XAMPP MySql in my.ini to 3307 and also changed the port in the XAMPP MySql config to 3307 but that has not helped.

I also have tried to disable service.msc from the command prompt but when I start XAMPP MySql service, I get a User Account Control pop-up which I click on "Yes" to allow.

It the gives me "Attempting to start MySQL service..." on the XAMPP Control Panel but never connects. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Did you installed your XAMPP in the default directory and running it as an administrator? This solved it for me once ;)

Comment: Don't make random changes, start by looking at the log files to see what the problem is. And *I get a User Account Control pop-up which I click on "Yes" to allow* is perfectly normal: just click Yes as requested.

Comment: Below is my error log file: